# Crystal Reports Primavera V9 "Fazer filtro sobre mapa a partir do form primavera"

Tags: crystal-reports

[Crystal Reporter]
[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ2ks.png)

Tenho essa tela, preciso construir um mapa que me mostra a Análise Mensal e Anual
ao mesmo tempo, mas, a partir de uma query e não tabelas específicas só que nessa query preciso de um filtro que é o ano (2019) da Imagem acima.

Como faço para pegar o 2019 do form inserir no mapa sem utilizar parâmetros? segue a query( o ano (2019) precisa vir do form):

```
select *
from (

select a.rubrica, 
Jan=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=1 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0) ,
Fev=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=2 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Marc=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=3 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Abr=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=4 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Mai=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=5 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Jun=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=6 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Jul=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=7 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Ago=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=8 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Sept=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=9 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Outb=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=10 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Nov=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=11 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0),
Dez=isnull((select sum(jan.acum) from AcRubricas jan where jan.rubrica=a.rubrica and month(dataac)=12 and year(dataac)=2019 ),0) 
from AcRubricas a where year(a.DataAc)=2019  group by a.Rubrica) mensal
inner join
(select rubrica,sum(Acum) as Acumulado,sum(orca) as Orcamento,( sum(orca) - sum(Acum)) as desvio from AcRubricas where  year(DataAc)=2019 group by rubrica) anual on anual.rubrica = mensal.Rubrica
```

Answer (score 0):

Diria que o mais simples,é criar uma view com base nessa query, retirando o filtro por Ano e agrupando os dados por Ano. Depois crias um mapa novo com base no existente. Adicionas a tua View ao mapa, podes fazer o link à tabela existente, por exemplo pela Rubrica, tendo assim o filtro das rubricas seleccionadas na janela. Dentro desse mapa tens lá um campo "Ano" ("formula field"), que é passado pelo Primavera. Usas esse campo para filtrar os dados a apresentar.

Comment: muitas vezes tenho tido problemas ao filtrar os dados a apresentar e evito usar porque ao fazer o somatório usar todos os dados até os não apresentados. obgdo pela sugestão. Percebi que não tenho hipótese sem os parâmetros é isso? fiz um mapa novo e estou tendo um outro erro.  segue o erro:"Esse nome de campo não é conhecido.
Detalhes: errorKind
Erro no arquivo BALS01 {5B2E11DD-6324-4390-8E03-157B7850BFA2}.rpt:
Erro na fórmula Record Selection: 
'{AcumuladosRubricas.posto}=1'
Esse nome de campo não é conhecido.
Detalhes: errorKind"